# How do I check there are multiple elements that contain something? - Cypress

Tags: cypress, assertion

I am trying to check that a list contains 2 specific entries using Cypress.

I have tried:

```
cy.get('ul.messages_list')
            .children()
            .contains('text')
            .and('contain', 'emailAddress)
            .should('have.length', 2)
```

The problem is that once I use .contains() it is in a single element and I cannot check that there are multiple of them.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const messages = cy.get('ul.messages_list').children();

messages.contains('text');
messages.contains('emailAddress');

messages.should('have.length', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `.contains('text')` with `.should('contain', 'text')`.

This way you should be able to chain assertions with `.and()`:

```js
cy.get('ul.messages_list')
  .children()
  .should('contain', 'text')
  .and('contain', 'emailAddress)
  .and('have.length', 2)
```

Comment: I know time is passed and does not exactly fit for this example, but for the records if who is reading is searching for filtering a list of elements by text, can be done with: `.filter(':contains(Contact)')` - e.g. `cy.get('#list').children('li').find('a').filter(':contains(Contact Me)').then($children => { cy.log($children) })`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Would this work for you?

```
cy.get('ul.messages_list').children().should(($children) => {
            expect($children).to.contain('text');
            expect($children).to.contain('emailaddress);
            expect($children.length).to.eq(2);
        })
```

I'm a total Cypress noob of about 8 hours eperience so you might have to do some tweaking :-)

Comment: Thank you for replying but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work as it is asserting the length on all the children...

Error: Timed out retrying: expected 30 to equal 2

Comment: Yes, my example asserts that there are two, and only two children. What exactly are you expecting to be 2 in your example?
Adding some more details about what you are testing on and what you are trying to do might help.
If what you want is to check for the presence of a specific text and a specific email you don't really need to check the number, do you?

Comment: I am trying to verify that 2 of the children contain that information. I do need to check that there are 2 of them. I need to check that there are 2 entries with the same information

Comment: Maybe you can use filter(): https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter.html#Usage

Comment: @Finney14 does your yielded subject have children elements like <li>? If so, do they have any attribute defined? Could you provide the HTML of your component?